# While loop skips the first `fgets()` on second iteration

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets, input-buffer

I know questions like this get asked all the time, and I have read several, however, I never use `scanf()` in my code like all the other ones, so I cannot find a comparable question.  I don't know why on the second, third, fourth and so on iterations, the while loop is skipping my first `fgets()`.

Code:

```
    int main()
{
    char word[40];
    char answer[2];
    while(true) {
        printf("Please enter word: ");
        fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
        printf("Your word is: %s\n", word);
        printf("Would you like to go again?");
        fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);
        printf("%d\n", strcmp(answer, "F"));
        if (strcmp(answer, "F") == 0) {
            printf("breaking");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("continuing");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter word: Hey
Your word is: Hey

Would you like to go again?Y
Please enter word: Your word is: 

Would you like to go again?Y
Please enter word: Your word is: 

Would you like to go again?Y
```

...etc.

I figure this has something to do with clearing the input buffer, and I have tried several things, but nothing is working.  Second day messing around with C, so I don't understand to much of it. (Python was easier lol)

Comment: After fgets you probably want to clear the remainder of the input line if it didn't read a whole line

Comment: @user3121023: it is the answer, and you could make an answer with it...

Comment: We need a National Programmers Day - honor all the programmers that struggled so we can just take plain English and compile it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter `Y<ENTER>`, then you have 2 characters in the input buffer: `Y` and `\n`. Since `answer` is a `char[2]` and `fgets` always writes a C-String, the string saved in `answer` will be `"Y"`.

The newline character remains in the input buffer, so the next `fgets` reads the remainder of the input buffer. Because its a newline, `fgets` reads only the newline, thus `word` will have the string `"\n"`.

You can declare the array `answer` with a larger dimension (at least 3) or use `word` instead. If you choose the former, then you should do

```
char answer[10];
...
if (strcmp(answer, "F\n") == 0)
   ...
```

**edit**

I'd like to add a quote from the `fgets` man page, this summarizes how `fgets`
work.

> *man fgets*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `fgets()` reads  in  **at  most  one less than `size` characters** from `stream` and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`.
>   **Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**.  A terminating null byte (`'\0'`)
>   is  stored  after  the  last character in the buffer.